# problem in connecting qradiobutton and qtab widget

Tags: c++, qt

**Question**

i have more than 5 radio buttons in my software and i want that when i click a radio button

then the text related to that button appears into the Qtab widget.

but i tried a lot but when i click a radio button the text related to that radio button

doesn't appear into the Qtabwidget.

my header file v_lab.h is here at pastebin(http://www.pastebin.org/880642)

at line 42 the function void peeyush(bool) is used to change the text

my header file v_lab.cpp is here at pastebin[(http://www.pastebin.org/880690](http://www.pastebin.org/880690))

at line 128 of file v_lab.cpp i calling constructor

so please help me in changing the text in tab widget when i click on the radio button named as Binary Search

-Thanks

Comment: @Dummy00001:ya i will surly do that because i am new in this forum so i done this mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Pass your main widget as the parent of the `algorithm` widget you are creating. Without that it's leaking memory anyway. To do this, pass a pointer to the instance of the main widget to the constructor of the `algorithm`.

```
new algorithm(string2, this);
```

Why is `algorithm` a widget anyway? That's not a very good approach.

If I were you, I'd create an `Algorithm` class with pure virtual functions, and subclass it for each algorithm implementation. `connect` the `toggle` signals of the radio buttons to different slots, and instantiate the chosen subclass in them.

Comment: can you explain me how can i make my widget as a parent??

Comment: Thanks Tamas,I was doing some mistake in connect.I  solved it.Thanks.

Comment: new edited code is at    http://www.pastebin.org/883834

http://www.pastebin.org/883832